# Error CS0030 Cannot convert type 'object' to 'System.TypedReference'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

I can't compile the following code with latest version VS2017 build 15.5.0, I did not have this problem before.

```
 void MyMethod(object[] objects)
 {
    TypedReference.SetTypedReference((TypedReference)objects[0], objects[1]);
 }
```

I reported to Microsoft
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/166353/error-cs0030-cannot-convert-type-object-to-systemt.html

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce this easily. My guess is that it's related to the new `Span<T>` work (https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.2/span-safety.md). That limits boxing and unboxing for certain types.